# MySQL fetch row and undefined variable error

Tags: php, mysql

I keep getting the following errors.  The `$query` produces a 1300 result list.  When I run `echo $query` I get the following MySQL error:

> [25-Aug-2016 21:38:32 America/New_York] PHP Warning:  mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in song.php on line 285
>
> [25-Aug-2016 21:38:32 America/New_York] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: song_hash in song.php on line 292

```
$query = "select " . $query_data . " from " . $query_tables . " where " . $query_where;
//echo $query;
$result = mysql_query($query,$database);

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){

    $key = $row[0];
    $song_hash[$key] = ($song_hash[$key] + 1);  
    
}

$largest = max($song_hash);
```

Comment: make sure the query is valid, and we can only guess what that is

Comment: Where is `$song_hash` defined?

Comment: Please consider migrating away from the `mysql_*` functions, which were deprecated in PHP 5.5 and completely removed in PHP 7. Instead, use `mysqli_*` or PDO.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

when you run `echo query` and you get those errors it simply means you don't have a query..
try hardcoding the query for debugging,

also you need to initialize your song_hash array

Answer (score 0):

In order to help you the contents of $query_data, $query_tables and $query_where needed. You can also print the error with mysql_error(). More likely you will be able to find out the solution from that output.

http://php.net/mysql_error